# Parse line in OCaml from a file

Tags: file, parsing, ocaml

I am very new to OCaml and I need to write a function which parses each line of a file into a List of three element.

In the following example, i want to parse Aemilia, np and Aemilia_____1

```
Aemilia 100 np  [pred="Aemilia_____1<Suj:(sn)>",@hum,@first_name,cat=np,@fs]    Aemilia_____1   Default fs  %default    nc-1fs
```

And extract_line would return

```
Aemilia; np; Aemilia_____1 (I guess this is string * string * string)
```

Actually I have something like this but I don't know how to implement it (in C it would be easy :-/ )

```ml
let extract_line str = 

;;

let rec extract ic = 
  let accum = [] in
    let line = In_channel.input_line ic in
      match line with 
        | None -> accum::[]
        | Some x -> accum :: extract_line x :: extract ic

  In_channel.close ic;;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't give enough information about the possible forms of your input lines to solve this problem carefully.

It's reasonable to assume you want the 1st, 3rd, and 5th "words" (whitespace-separated values) from the line.

```
let get_words =
    let re = Str.regexp "[ \t]+" in
    fun s ->
        Str.split re s

let extract ic =
    let rec loop accum =
        match input_line ic with
        | line ->
            (match get_words line with
            | w1 :: _ ::  w3 :: _ :: w5 :: _ ->
                loop ((w1, w3, w5) :: accum)
            | _ -> loop accum
            )
        | exception End_of_file -> List.rev accum
     in
     loop []
```

The fourth value on the line looks pretty complicated. If it can contain embedded spaces you'll need to do a much more careful analysis of each line. (E.g., you might need to look for matching square brackets. But can the value also contain brackets?)

(You say this would be easy in C, but it's interesting to think about how your imagined C code would behave in the presence of very long input lines. Once you handle these kinds of things properly, C becomes much more difficult in my experience. Every program becomes a memory management problem.)